# Defining a big matrix for iterative algorithm

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, linear-algebra

I need to solve this [image: systemOfEq]system of equations with Seidel and Jacobi methods, so I tried to define a big matrix in Wolfram.

I have read documentation, and I wrote the following command that should help me, but it is now working:

```
Table[If[i == j, a], If[i == j + 1, 1], If[i + 1 == j, 1], 
 If[i + 2 == j, 1/b], {i, 100}, {j, 100}]
```

Can we work in wolfram with such big matrixes? If yes, how I should declare them?

And maybe someone can advise me where I can read about iterative algorithms on matrixes in Wolfram?

Comment: If we are using decimal values rather than exact values, 100 x 100 is actually not at all large.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll illustrate with a smaller example, using the Jacobi method. Since the matrix is sparse it makes sense to use the `SparseArray` structure from the Wolfram Language.

```
a = b = 10.;
n = 16;
mat = SparseArray[{{i_, i_} -> a, {i_, j_} /; j == i - 1 :> 
     1., {i_, j_} /; j == i + 1 :> 1., {i_, j_} /; j == i + 2 :> 1/b}, n];
rhs = N@Range[n];
```

For the iterations we separate the (dominant) diagonal and the rest of the matrix.

```
diag = Normal[Diagonal[mat]];
rest = mat - DiagonalMatrix[diag];
```

We'll initialize a result and do a few Jacobi iterations.

```
x[0] = ConstantArray[0., n];
Do[x[j] = 1/diag*(rhs - rest.x[j - 1]), {j, 4}];
```

What is this approximated result now?

```
(* In[512]:= *)x[4]

(* Out[512]= {0.0809433, 0.1635632, 0.2460271, 0.328511, 0.4109949, \
0.4934788, 0.5759627, 0.6584466, 0.7409305, 0.8234144, 0.9059, \
0.988435, 1.071278, 1.15244, 1.2357, 1.47554} *)
```

Here is what a direct linear solver gives.

```
soln = LinearSolve[mat, rhs]

(* Out[518]= {0.0811406188159, 0.163937166886, 0.24656644955, \
0.329212627692, 0.411857099219, 0.494501743134, 0.577146369797, \
0.659790996402, 0.742435624897, 0.825080412827, 0.90772341803, \
0.990368288034, 1.07317118838, 1.15422513249, 1.23694695631, \
1.47630530437} *)
```

We can see they are already not too far apart.

```
Norm[x[4] - soln]

(* Out[522]= 0.00519376049093 *)
```

A better iteration would use e.g. `FixedPoint` and stop when the change is less than some epsilon.

By the way, this can be carried out in exact arithmetic as well. Expect large numerators and denominators...

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

## New Method

```
n = 100;
method2[n_] := SparseArray[{
 {i_, i_} -> a,
 {i_, j_} /; (i == j + 1 || i == j - 1) -> 1,
 {i_, j_} /; i == j - 2 -> 1/b},
 {n, n}
]

method1[n].Array[x, n] // RepeatedTiming;
method2[n].Array[x, n] // RepeatedTiming;
{#[[;; , 1]], SameQ @@ #[[;; , 2]]} &@Out[{-2, -1}]
```

> {{0.020, 0.0062}, True}

## Original Method

```
n = 10;
method1[n_] := Table[
 Which[i == j, a, i == j + 1, 1, i + 1 == j, 1, i + 2 == j, 1/b, True, 0],
 {i, n}, {j, n}
];
method1[n].Array[x, n] // TableForm
```

```
(* a x[1]+x[2]+x[3]/b
x[1]+a x[2]+x[3]+x[4]/b
x[2]+a x[3]+x[4]+x[5]/b
x[3]+a x[4]+x[5]+x[6]/b
x[4]+a x[5]+x[6]+x[7]/b
x[5]+a x[6]+x[7]+x[8]/b
x[6]+a x[7]+x[8]+x[9]/b
x[7]+a x[8]+x[9]+x[10]/b
x[8]+a x[9]+x[10]
x[9]+a x[10] *)
```

As for the resources on iterative methods, I'll keep looking.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But can this code add each element from each sum to a separate element of matrix?

Comment: @YuraHolubeu Sorry, I don't understand the question.

Comment: Thanks, I will look to this code as soon as possible :)

Answer (score 3):

An alternative way to construct a `SparseArray` using [`Band`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Band.html):

```
sa[n_] := SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> a, 
     Band[{2, 1}] -> 1, 
     Band[{1, 2}] -> 1,
     Band[{1, 3}] -> 1/b},
   {n, n}]

Array[x, 10] # & /@ sa[10] // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> $\small\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccccccc}
>  a x(1) & x(2) & \frac{x(3)}{b} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  x(1) & a x(2) & x(3) & \frac{x(4)}{b} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & x(2) & a x(3) & x(4) & \frac{x(5)}{b} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & x(3) & a x(4) & x(5) & \frac{x(6)}{b} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & x(4) & a x(5) & x(6) & \frac{x(7)}{b} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & x(5) & a x(6) & x(7) & \frac{x(8)}{b} & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & x(6) & a x(7) & x(8) & \frac{x(9)}{b} & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & x(7) & a x(8) & x(9) & \frac{x(10)}{b} \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & x(8) & a x(9) & x(10) \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & x(9) & a x(10) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

**Note:** Using `Band` is faster than `method2` in ThatGravityGuy's answer:

```
n = 100;
sa[n].Array[x, n]; // RepeatedTiming// First
```

> 0.00051

```
method2[n].Array[x, n]; //RepeatedTiming// First
```

> 0.0071

Comment: Thank you very much, this looks like an ideal answer!

Comment: @YuraHolubeu, you are  welcome. And welcome to mma.se.