# easiest way to construct the following determinant

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

What is the easiest way to construct the following determinant?[image]]

`p` is variable, I want to vary value of p each time and get the appropriate determinant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do it would be

```
mat[p_] := SparseArray[{
  {i_, i_} :> B[i - 1],
  {i_, j_} /; i == j + 1 :> A[j - 1],
  {i_, j_} /; i == j - 1 :> CC[j - 1]
  },
 p + 1
 ]
Det@mat[p]
```

For example

```
With[{p = 2},
 SparseArray[{
   {i_, i_} :> B[i - 1],
   {i_, j_} /; i == j + 1 :> A[j - 1],
   {i_, j_} /; i == j - 1 :> CC[j - 1]
   },
  p + 1
  ]
 ]
Det@%
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  B(0) & \text{CC}(1) & 0 \\
>  A(0) & B(1) & \text{CC}(2) \\
>  0 & A(1) & B(2) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$
>
> B[0] B[1] B[2] - A[0] B[2] CC[1] - A[1] B[0] CC[2]

But the computation time quickly increases with `p` since the elements are symbolic.  For example, with `p = 17`,

```
With[{p = 17},
    SparseArray[{
      {i_, i_} :> B[i - 1],
      {i_, j_} /; i == j + 1 :> A[j - 1],
      {i_, j_} /; i == j - 1 :> CC[j - 1]
      },
     p + 1
 ]
] // Det // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 2.7

But, if the elements are numeric quantities,

```
SeedRandom[1234]
With[{p = 17},
    SparseArray[{
      {i_, i_} :> RandomReal[],
      {i_, j_} /; i == j + 1 :> RandomReal[],
      {i_, j_} /; i == j - 1 :> RandomReal[]
      },
     p + 1
 ]
] // Det // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.0020

the calculation is no problem.

Comment: thanks a lot. In fact A,B and C are some functions which become determined by initial values.

Answer (score 6):

Since you indicate you're interested only in the determinant, a recursive procedure is faster:

```
ClearAll[det];
det[0] = 1;
det[1] = b[0];
mem : det[p_] := mem = b[p - 1] det[p - 1] - a[p - 2] c[p - 1] det[p - 2];

d1 = det[15]; // AbsoluteTiming
d3 = With[{n = 15},  (* J.M.'s RecurrenceTable[] idea *)
    First[RecurrenceTable[{d[p] == 
        b[p - 1] d[p - 1] - a[p - 2] c[p - 1] d[p - 2], d[0] == 1, 
       d[1] == b[0]}, d, {p, n, n}]]]; // AbsoluteTiming
d2 = Det@sa[15]; // AbsoluteTiming (*sa[p] = SparseArray solution (I used @kglr's)*) 

d1 - d2 // Simplify
d1 - d3 // Simplify
(*
  {0.000188, Null}
  {0.000936, Null}
  {0.391194, Null}

  0
  0
*)
```

The results are memoized, so that if you need to compute the determinant for another value of `p`, the new result is built on top of any previous computations.  As long as storing the results is not a problem (in terms of RAM), it should make things faster.

Comment: You'd think this method would be built into *M* somewhere, but I can't find it.

Comment: Of course, you can use `RecurrenceTable[]` for this as well: `With[{n = 15}, First[RecurrenceTable[{d[p] == b[p - 1] d[p - 1] - a[p - 2] c[p - 1] d[p - 2], d[0] == 1, d[1] == b[0]}, d, {p, n, n}]]]`

Answer (score 4):

An alternative, and faster, way to construct the `SparseArray` using [`Band`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Band.html):

```
sa[n_] := SparseArray[{
   Band[{1, 1}] -> Array[b, n, 0], 
   Band[{2, 1}] -> Array[a, n - 1, 0], 
   Band[{1, 2}] -> Array[c, n - 1]}, 
  {n, n}]

sa[10] // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccccccc}
>  b(0) & c(1) & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  a(0) & b(1) & c(2) & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & a(1) & b(2) & c(3) & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & a(2) & b(3) & c(4) & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & a(3) & b(4) & c(5) & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a(4) & b(5) & c(6) & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a(5) & b(6) & c(7) & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a(6) & b(7) & c(8) & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a(7) & b(8) & c(9) \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a(8) & b(9) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: Originally I thought to use your `Band` method (from the other very similar [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/207804/46490) recently), but didn't think to create the element vectors.