# How to obtain the Gauss-Seidel iterative results in this form?

Tags: linear-algebra, output-formatting

I need to use the Gauss Seidel iterative method to solve the linear equations $\left\{\begin{array}{l}
8 x_{1}-3 x_{2}+2 x_{3}=20 \\
4 x_{1}+11 x_{2}-x_{3}=33 \\
6 x_{1}+3 x_{2}+12 x_{3}=36
\end{array}\right.$ .

```
(*GaussSedel iterative method*)

X[0] = {0, 0, 0};
b = {20, 33, 36};
A = ( {
    {8, -3, 2},
    {4, 11, -1},
    {6, 3, 12}
   } );
DI = DiagonalMatrix@Diagonal[A];
L = LowerTriangularize[-A, -1];
U = UpperTriangularize[-A, 1];
B = IdentityMatrix[3] - Inverse[DI - L].A;
G = Inverse[DI - L].U
f = Inverse[DI - L].b
```

But the above code can only get the iteration formula in the form of $\left(\begin{array}{c}
x 1[k+1] \\
x 2[k+1] \\
x 3[k+1]
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & \frac{3}{8} & -\frac{1}{4} \\
0 & -\frac{3}{22} & \frac{2}{11} \\
0 & -\frac{27}{176} & \frac{7}{88}
\end{array}\right) \cdot\left(\begin{array}{c}
x 1[k] \\
x 2[k] \\
x 3[k]
\end{array}\right)+f^T$.

But the reference answer is in the form of (the main difference is that the corner mark `k+1` gradually appears in the iteration formula on the right) $\left\{\begin{array}{l}
x_{1}^{(k+1)}=\left(20+3 x_{2}^{(k)}-2 x_{3}^{(k)}\right) / 8 \\
x_{2}^{(k+1)}=\left(33-4 x_{1}^{(k+1)}+x_{3}^{(k)}\right) / 11, \quad k=0,1, \cdots \\
x_{3}^{(k+1)}=\left(36-6 x_{1}^{(k+1)}-3 x_{2}^{(k+1)}\right) / 12
\end{array}\right.$.

I want to know what I can do to get an iterative formula like the reference answer.

$$\left(\begin{array}{c}
x 1[k+1] \\
x 2[k+1] \\
x 3[k+1]
\end{array}\right)=
\text { MapThread }\left[\text { Dot },\left\{\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & \frac{3}{8} & -\frac{1}{4} \\
-\frac{4}{11} & 0 & \frac{1}{11} \\
-\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{4} & 0
\end{array}\right) ,\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & x 2[k] & x 3[k] \\
x 1[k+1] & 0 & x 3[k+1] \\
x 1[k+1] & x 2[k+1] & \theta
\end{array}\right)\right\}\right]+\left(\begin{array}{c}
\frac{2 \theta}{8} \\
3 \\
3
\end{array}\right)$$

**Note:** the example used is from page 189 of [this book](http://book.ucdrs.superlib.net/views/specific/2929/bookDetail.jsp?dxNumber=000006641172&d=CB6E1ED34FB8B2B0879DD74D4A4AA569&fenlei=130116).

Comment: Might find some useful code [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/207804/defining-a-big-matrix-for-iterative-algorithm). It avoids explicit inverses.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your data for the matrix $A$ and $b$, seems like your computation is correct, according to the alternative formulation of [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Seidel_method),

```
b = {20, 33, 36};
A = {{8, -3, 2}, {4, 11, -1}, {6, 3, 12}};
L = LowerTriangularize@A;
U = UpperTriangularize[A, 1];
GaussSeidelIter[xv_] := Inverse[L].(b - U.xv);
xv = {Subscript[x, 1], Subscript[x, 2], Subscript[x, 3]};
-Inverse[L].U // Simplify // MatrixForm
GaussSeidelIter@xv // Simplify // MatrixForm
```

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & \frac{3}{8} & -\frac{1}{4} \\
 0 & -\frac{3}{22} & \frac{2}{11} \\
 0 & -\frac{27}{176} & \frac{7}{88} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{8} \left(20 + 3 x_2-2 x_3\right) \\
\frac{1}{22} \left(46 -3 x_2+4 x_3\right) \\
\frac{1}{176} \left(216 -27 x_2+14 x_3\right)
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Its looks like either the refernce solution is faulty or your $A$ and $b$ do not match the ones used for the reference solution.

Comment: Thank you. Please pay attention to the corner marker `k + 1`. You will find that this is different from the format I asked for.

Comment: Thank you. I have given the desired output form in the following answer.

Answer (score 0):

The approximate results can be obtained according to the formula in the textbook:

```
n = 3; 
b = {20, 33, 36}; a = {{8, -3, 2}, {4, 11, -1}, {6, 3, 12}}; 
Δx[
  i_] := (b[[i]] - Sum[a[[i, j]]*x[j, k + 1], {j, 1, i - 1}] - 
        Sum[a[[i, j]]*x[j, k], {j, i + 1, n}])/a[[i, i]]
Thread[Table[x[i, k + 1], {i, 1, n}] == 
  Table[Δx[i], {i, 1, n}]]
```