# How to define some functions automatically?

Tags: function-construction, linear-algebra

I want to use Gauss-Seidel iteration to solve [this problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230187/how-to-obtain-the-gauss-seidel-iterative-results-in-this-form/230413#230413).

$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}
8 x_{1}-3 x_{2}+2 x_{3}=20 \\
4 x_{1}+11 x_{2}-x_{3}=33 \\
6 x_{1}+3 x_{2}+12 x_{3}=36
\end{array}\right.$$

```
n = 3; 
b = {20, 33, 36}; a = {{8, -3, 2}, {4, 11, -1}, {6, 3, 12}}; 
Δx[
  i_] := (b[[i]] - Sum[a[[i, j]]*x[j, k], {j, 1, i - 1}] - 
    Sum[a[[i, j]]*x[j, k - 1], 
          {j, i + 1, n}])/a[[i, i]]
Thread[Table[x[i, k], {i, 1, n}] == 
  Table[Δx[i], {i, 1, n}]]
```

I want to be able to use `Table[Hold[x[i, k_] := x[i, k] = Δx[i]], {i, 1, n}]` to automatically define functions instead of manually defining related functions as follows:

```
x[1, k_] := x[1, k] = (1/8)*(3*x[2, k - 1] - 2*x[3, k - 1] + 20)
x[2, k_] := x[2, k] = (1/11)*(-(4*x[1, k ]) + x[3, k - 1] + 33)
x[3, k_] := x[3, k] = (1/12)*(-(6*x[1, k ]) - 3*x[2, k ] + 36)
```

*That is, I want to use function `Table` to automatically define some functions.*

So that the following operations can be carried out automatically:

```
x[1, 0] = 1.; 
x[2, 0] = 1.;
x[3, 0] = 1.;
Table[{x[1, i], x[2, i], x[3, i]}, {i, 0, 10}]
LinearSolve[( {
   {8, -3, 2},
   {4, 11, -1},
   {6, 3, 12}
  } ), {20, 33, 36}]
```

What can I do to get the custom functions directly in the result?

**Update 1:**

The following code can implement batch custom functions:

```
Table[With[{i = i}, Hold[x[i, k_] := x[i, k] = i*k]], {i, 1, 3}]
ReleaseHold[%]
Table[{x[1, i], x[2, i], x[3, i]}, {i, 0, 3}]
```

But I don't know why the following code doesn't work in the same way:

```
n = 3;
b = {20, 33, 36}; a = {{8, -3, 2}, {4, 11, -1}, {6, 3, 12}};
Δx[i_] := (b[[i]] - Sum[a[[i, j]]*x[j, k], {j, 1, i - 1}] - 
    Sum[a[[i, j]]*x[j, k - 1], {j, i + 1, n}])/a[[i, i]]
Table[With[{i = i}, 
  Hold[x[i, k_] := x[i, k] = Δx[i]]], {i, 1, 3}]
ReleaseHold[%]
Table[{x[1, m], x[2, m], x[3, m]}, {m, 0, 1}]
```

I guess the local assignment of `k` may cause this problem, but I don't know how to solve this problem. Please help me.

Comment: Maybe it’s not exactly clear what you’re asking? At least to me it is not clear. If you define all of those expressions as you have written them, does it not run? What is the issue with it? Do errors appear? If so, what are they?

Comment: @CATrevillian Thank you for your comments. I've revised the problem statement.

Comment: Is the `Δx` function that you have what creates the functions you show below it that you want to define automatically? It seems to be so. This should not be entirely non-trivial to achieve then.

Comment: `Table[With[{i = i}, Hold[...i...]], {i, n}]` maybe.  See docs for `With`, under `Scope`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you. Can you write it in detail? I still can't meet the requirements by using `Table[With[{i = i}, 
  Hold[x[i, k_] := x[i, k] = \[CapitalDelta]x[i]]], {i, 1, n}]`.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant.

Comment: @MichaelE2 But `Table[With[{i = i},    Hold[x[i, k_] := x[i, k] = \[CapitalDelta]x[i]]], {i, 1, n}]` can't define the function I want, so that the code `x[1, 0] = 1.; 
x[2, 0] = 1.;
x[3, 0] = 1.;
Table[{x[1, i], x[2, i], x[3, i]}, {i, 0, 10}]` can't run.

Comment: IDK, and please understand I don't have time to figure out what you want to do this evening. All I saw was `Table` and `Hold`, and you need `With` to insert the value of `i`, as I showed. It does exactly what I would want it to do. If it doesn't work for you, I can only think you don't know what `Hold` does and decided to stick it in for no reason. What happens if you leave it out or use `ReleaseHold`?

Comment: @Alittlemouseonthepampas is what I posted not what you are looking for? It does it automatically. If you’re asking to perform the initial conditions/values automatically, that is something that does not work from an algorithmic standpoint, if I’m using the correct terminology. You would need to redefine your function definitions if that’s what you want to do, which is quite outside the scope of this question & would involve the use not of Mathematica, but pen & paper to derive the proper expression so as to not need to define x[1, 0], x[2, 0], and x[3, 0] yourself.

Comment: @CATrevillian Thank you for your answer. I have posted a feasible method below. I hope you can provide more methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you’re looking for:

```
ClearAll[n,b,x,Δx];
n = 3; 
b = {20, 33, 36}; a = {{8, -3, 2}, {4, 11, -1}, {6, 3, 12}};
x[i_,k_]:=x[i,k]=Δx[i,k];
x[1,0]=1.;
x[2,0]=1.;
x[3,0]=1.;
Δx[
  i_,k_] := (b[[i]] - Sum[a[[i, j]]*x[j, k], {j, 1, i - 1}] - 
    Sum[a[[i, j]]*x[j, k - 1], 
          {j, i + 1, n}])/a[[i, i]];
Table[{x[1,i],x[2,i],x[3,i]},{i,0,10}]
```

> `{{1.,1.,1.},{2.625,2.13636,1.15341},{3.01278,2.0093,0.991284},{3.00567,1.99715,0.99788},{2.99946,2.,1.00027},{2.99993,2.00005,1.00002},{3.00001,2.,0.999994},{3.,2.,1.},{3.,2.,1.},{3.,2.,1.},{3.,2.,1.}}`

Where the trick seems to be to define the initial conditions of the function `x[i, k]` after it is defined. In this way, you overwrite the definitions you defined previously, or you are defining the results that the function needs to access that will never be defined by it to start.

If this is not what you are after, please further clarify what you are interested in obtaining?

Comment: If only the Gauss-Seidel iterates are desired, this is more straightforward: `With[{mat = {{8, -3, 2}, {4, 11, -1}, {6, 3, 12}}, vec = N[{20, 33, 36}], init = N[{1, 1, 1}]}, Block[{lf = LinearSolve[N[LowerTriangularize[mat]]], su = UpperTriangularize[mat, 1]}, FixedPointList[lf[vec - su.#] &, init]]]`

Answer (score 0):

A simple method:

```
n = 3;
b = {20, 33, 36}; a = {{8, -3, 2}, {4, 11, -1}, {6, 3, 12}};
x[1, 0] = 1.;
x[2, 0] = 1.;
x[3, 0] = 1.;
Δx[
  i_] := (b[[i]] - Sum[a[[i, j]]*x[j, k], {j, 1, i - 1}] - 
    Sum[a[[i, j]]*x[j, k - 1], {j, i + 1, n}])/a[[i, i]]
Table[Hold[x[m1, k_] := x[m1, k] = c] /. m1 -> m /. 
  c -> Δx[m], {m, 1, 3}]
ReleaseHold[%]
Table[{x[1, m], x[2, m], x[3, m]}, {m, 0, 3}]
```